# Web service in java using IIS

Tags: java, android, web-services, iis

Hi i am developing android application. I am using web service to communicate with the server. I am creating web service in java. I want to deploy it on IIS(Internet Information System Manager). And i am using eclipse. Can i use IIS for deploy the web service.? If yes how. Plz give me suggestions. I can do it with apache tom cat but i want to do it with iis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to host Java web service on something allowing that - for example Tomcat. Than you need to configure IIS to forward requests for Java services to Tomcat - check [Apache Tomcat Connector](http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/webserver_howto/iis.html).

Generally IIS is extensible through something called ISAPI extension - it is native library forwarding processing of specific request to correct component. There are ISAPI extensions to process request in Java but they most often only forward request to another server - I believe that is what Tomcat Connector does.

Comment: Use Tomcat directly - I don't see any added value by using IIS for Java Web service.