# How to host a Java web service in IIS

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services

I have created one web service in java using eclipse.Can any one tell me how to run that web service through IIS.

Comment: This is an interesting question.

Comment: show what you tried, or this will be closed quickly, I am not suprise it has lasted 23 mins honestly!

Comment: @RosdiKasim is not so interesting. There are [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2256084/1065197) and [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7724091/1065197) that explain "deploying" a Java Web Application in IIS and use this web app as producer of web services.

Comment: Also, why you want to deploy your web service through IIS? You can use a tomcat or jetty lightweight servlet container to do this job.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't. MS IIS can only host web applications developed in Microsoft technologies, like ASP, .NET and also in PHP. Can't host Java applications.

In order to host Web Services developed in Java (I suppose you used Apache Axis), you need at least a servlet container (aka Java web server) or a full Java EE container: Free and Open Source like Apache Tomcat, Red Hat JBoss, Apache Jeronimo, Oracle Glassfish; commercial like Oracle WebLogic, IBM WebSphere...

You could need also additional libraries used like Apache Axis.

Depending on your Eclipse configuration, you can deploy it in an embedded Tomcat server within Eclipse in order to test it.

Answer (score 1):

No! You can't. Java Web service application *should* be hosted in [Java EE container](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnabo.html), [or](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/wiverson/archive/2009/04/google_app_engi.html) you can run [Web Services in Java SE 6.0](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/07/03/jax-ws-web-services-without-ee-containers.html).

Comment: Then how can i host my web service on cloud?

Comment: Service providers will provide *container* and other *software/API* - [Platform as a service (PaaS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloud_computing#Platform_as_a_service_.28PaaS.29)

Comment: *Then how can i host my web service on cloud?*, you think *the cloud* runs on IIS?

Comment: @JarrodRoberson First of all i need to know the difference between IIS and cloud server. Can you please make me clear about this one

Comment: there is no such thing as *the cloud* or a *cloud server*, it is marketing speak, go back and do some research and come back with a specific question that might have a specific answer.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson don't mistake me, actually i am self learner to java/eclipse and web service too.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson http://www.softwareagility.gr/index.php?q=node/29 this is the link i am referring to create a web service in java using eclipse, now i got struggle in "UDDI" can you tell me for what purpose UDDI is using here

Answer (score 0):

Well if you insist, I suppose you can use ISAPI plugin. Refer here for more details:

http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc-archive/jk2/jk/iishowto.html